# How do I set fan speed to max in Ubuntu?

Tags: fan, overheating, fancontrol

My laptop tends to run really hot and I don't think Ubuntu is increasing the fan rpm enough to match the rising temperature. I have looked at a few fan speed related tutorials and they all go into installing lm_sensors. However, I don't wish to monitor the CPU temperature at all. I would instead like to set the fan speed to its maximum. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you checked your firmware/BIOS settings?

Comment: Better to just try and solve the overheating problem. Do you have a Nvidia card? If so, what version driver? What version Ubuntu? How old is the laptop? There may be a lot of dust build-up inside that requires cleaning. The CPU thermal paste may require cleaning and re-application. Install lm_sensors to determine what the actual temps are.

Comment: @heynnema There's no dust for sure. I open the case and blast with compressed air about once a month. Its a macbook air. While in the macOS it runs really cool, like 28 or 29 degrees celsius. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Look at installing `thermald`. It has a custom configuration file that can be used maintain a certain max temp.